# How to shuffle a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is the order of dictionary decided at first print?

I mean that every time when I print the same dictionary, it entries return in the same order. How can I show entries in different orders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your python version. In versions older than Python 3.6, dictionaries are not ordered. Printing them *may* give different results each time. This means you cannot rely on them to return the same order, but neither should you assume that they return keys in a proper random order.

However, in newer versions, python dictionaries are ordered, and the print result will be the same.

In case of ordered dictionaries, the order of a dictionary is not decided when calling print for the first time, but at the moment of creation.

For Python 3.6 or later you can shuffle your dictionary keys and create a new dict:

```
import random
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
l = list(d.items())
random.shuffle(l)
d = dict(l)
```

Comment: "Printing them will give different results each time." No, even in prior versions, printing the dictionary would be *consistent* if *arbitrary*.